# Why are Node modules not loading in html file?

Tags: node.js

I am trying to load, that is, require node modules into an index.html file.

I have installed all the node modules - in /node_modules

and in the package.json file I have:    "mysql": "^2.18.1",

If I create a JS file using:

`const http = require('http');`
`const mysql = require('mysql');`

(plus other relevant code)

and run that file with: node filename, I get the required output of a MYSQL table in the browser.

When I try the:

`const http = require('http');`
`const mysql = require('mysql');`

in the index.html file, I get the message: "ReferenceError: require is not defined".

Now, I know that this is a common JS message when vars are not defined or files cannot be found, but I do not understand why the modules are being found 'locally', that is when run in the terminal with the node command above, but not when the same code - const... is being used in the JS area in the html file.

In short, is there some way to specify the path to the modules in the html file that I am missing? (I have tried various things with ./ etc.) Or, is there something else wrong?

Thanks PB

Comment: You can't use Node.js from a browser. You might want to take a look at [Electron](https://www.electronjs.org/).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is not possible to `require` Node.js modules from a webpage running inside a browser. A webpage can only access [Web APIs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API), like the DOM.

> Now, I know that this is a common JS message when vars are not defined or files cannot be found [...]

It's actually a message from the JS engine, saying that the `require` function was not found. Common JS is not available inside a browser either (unless you include it in your project).

Comment: Many thanks. I was beginning to suspect that I was on the wrong track, both in what I am trying to do and in the error message.